# How can I grep for a hyphenated string within a very long single line string?

Tags: grep

I am a Windows guy, so I am out of my element here. I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I have failed to obtain an answer after six hours of research, trial and error. It would make my week if a pro could weigh in!!

This is my string:

```
server ITW-F280 ITW-F280HQ-AV up numProc=1 numFD=5 mem=23720kB ITW-F280HQ-DHC up numProc=2 numFD=16 mem=47040kB ITW-F280HQ-NGF up numProc=1 numFD=4 mem=117424kB ITW-F280HQ-VPN up numProc=11 numFD=118 mem=2880536kB
```

The string within the aforementioned string that I wish to grep is `ITW-F280HQ-AV`. For context, this value changes depending on which firewall the command is executed on, but the one commonality is the `HQ-AV` tail—everything before that is different depending on the environment. In this example there are two hyphens, but other firewalls may only have the one common hyphen.

Here's what I have tried so far, to no avail...

Returns nothing:

```
grep '\b\W[[:space:]]*HQ-AV[[:space:]]'
```

Returns the entire string, unfiltered:

```
grep '\b\W[[:space:]]*AV[[:space:]]'
```

Returns the entire string, unfiltered:

```
grep '[[:space:]]*AV\b'
```

Returns only `-F280HQ-AV`, so this theoretically would work on firewalls w/ only one hyphen:

```
grep -o '\-\w*-AV\b
```

I have tried hundreds of combinations—far too many to list here. I have reviewed the documentation, but due to my weak Linux background, I am firing in the dark.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!! :)

Comment: `grep -o '\b\w\+*\-\w*-AV\b'` returns `ITW-F280HQ-AV`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by trimming everything before the desired string, leaving ONLY this:

```
ITW-F280HQ-AV up numProc=1 numFD=5 mem=23720kB ITW-F280HQ-DHC up numProc=2 numFD=16 mem=47040kB ITW-F280HQ-NGF up numProc=1 numFD=4 mem=117424kB ITW-F280HQ-VPN up numProc=11 numFD=118 mem=2880536kB
```

And then I used sed to trim everything after the first space:

```
sed 's/\s.*$//'
```

Hope this helps someone!